# How to generate random double number outside a specified range in Java?

Tags: java, math, random

Is there a way to generate random double value outside a specified range?

I know there is one within the range:

```
Random r = new Random();
double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
```

I would require one that is outside the range e.g

the range is 20 - 50 and I would like a number below 20 or higher than 50.

Could someone please advise?

Comment: I dont think thats possible, you will probably have to write a `if statement` that checks wether or not the generated number is in your range. if it is then generate another number

Comment: What are the outer bounds of those ranges then?

Comment: lazy answer: generate randoms and discard those within the range, anyway I guess it will be faster

Comment: Next time please specify that outside range 20 - 50 does not count minus and plus infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try somethink like this :

```
Random rnd = new Random();
double x=0;
do{
    x = rnd.nextDouble()*100;
}while(x>20 && x<50 );

    System.out.println(x);
    }
```

You generate a random double ( need multiply by 100 because generate double return value between 0 and 1 ) and loop while result >20 and <50

Comment: Thanks, I think this will do for now :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like (for numbers 1-20 and 50-100):

```
Random r = new Random();
double randomValue = r.nextDouble()*70;
if(randomValue>20) randomValue+=30;
```

It is not resource expensive and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `double`, **any** `double`, outside a specific range, then you you can take advantage of the fact that a `double` is represented by 64 bits, and you can convert any 64-bit value to a `double` using the `Double.longBitsToDouble` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();

    double d;
    do {
        d = Double.longBitsToDouble(r.nextLong());
    } while (d >= 20 && d <= 50);

    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Comment: Use this only if you do not care at all about the distribution of the values you randomly generate. This is far from uniform.

Comment: Of course it isn’t. Read the OP, it doesn’t specify any outside range nor request for uniformness.

Comment: Your solution gets points for cleverness and diversity, but it would most likely fail a casual reader who simply copy&pasted your code without knowing what they are doing. It would be wise to warn people about what exactly it means to do this so we do not end up with buggy software linked to your solution!

Answer (score -1):

First of all you always need some upper bound for the number you're generating, so 'above rangeMax' won't really do. What you basically want is to have a number generated that falls into one of two ranges [0,minRange] or [maxRange, maxValue].

You can either go with the 'lazy approach' which is just generating a value between 0 and maxValue and generate a new one until you get on that does not fall into the [minRange,maxRange] range or you could do a two step generation process, i.e. generate a random number that determines whether you generate a number in the lower range or the upper range, for instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double result  = (new Random().nextInt(2)) == 0 ? generateInRange(0, 20) : generateInRange(50, Double.MAX_VALUE);
}

private static double generateInRange(double min, double max) {
    return new Random().nextDouble() * (max-min) + min;
}
```

This does give you a 50/50 chance of ending up in the lower and upper range, so you might want to tweak that.

Comment: This will mess up the random distribution so it is more likely getting a small number than a large number. That might be undesirable.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned the 50/50 chance. If you'd want to have it evenly distributed you'd have to take the range size into account and use something like `new Random().nextInt(minRange + (maxValue - maxRange)) < minRange`